# Multi-threaded code is not working [C, Pthread]

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu, unix, pthreads

I assumed that each producer thread would individually add values ​​to the buffer. But it seems that the same thread continues to fill the buffer.
But the output is not: the same thread is running until the context switch happens (guess).
I have to use only condition variable and mutex with pthread, without semaphore or sleep.
Is this the reason for the problem?
Using C on Ubuntu 22.04

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t fill = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t empty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

int buffer[10];
int cnt = 0;  // # of items in the buffer
int in = 0;  // index to add an item to buffer
int out = 0;  // index to read an item from buffer

void *producer();  //producer function
void *consumer();  //consumer function

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    pthread_t Pthread[5];
    pthread_t Cthread[5];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&Pthread[i], NULL, producer, NULL);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&Cthread[i], NULL, consumer, NULL);
        }
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_join(Pthread[i], NULL);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_join(Cthread[i], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}

void *producer(void *arg){
    while(1){
        int next_produced = rand();  // create a random integer
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        //======== critical section =============
        while (cnt == 10) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &mutex);
        }
        buffer[in] = next_produced;  // add the item
        in = (in + 1) % 10;  // move to next index
        cnt++;
        printf("Producer thread: %lu adds the value : %d\n",
                pthread_self(), next_produced);
        pthread_cond_signal(&fill);
        //======== critical section =============
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

void *consumer(void *arg){
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        //======== critical section =============
        while (cnt == 0){
            pthread_cond_wait(&fill, &mutex);
        }
        int next_consumed = buffer[out];  // read an item from buffer
        buffer[out] = 0;  // remove the item from buffer
        out = (out + 1) % 10;  // move to next index
        cnt--;
        printf("Consumer thread: %lu deletes the value : %d\n",
                pthread_self(),next_consumed);
        pthread_cond_signal(&empty);
        //======== critical section =============
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}
```

And here's a part of the result:

```
Producer thread: 140109028513344 adds the value : 1457620057
Producer thread: 140109028513344 adds the value : 1109246666
Producer thread: 140109028513344 adds the value : 34472492
Producer thread: 140109028513344 adds the value : 1658551151
Producer thread: 140109028513344 adds the value : 1646031817
Producer thread: 140109028513344 adds the value : 2114864384
Producer thread: 140109028513344 adds the value : 2019817090
Producer thread: 140109028513344 adds the value : 90771015
Producer thread: 140109028513344 adds the value : 1977802548
Producer thread: 140109028513344 adds the value : 1337378708
Consumer thread: 140108921554496 deletes the value : 1457620057
Consumer thread: 140108921554496 deletes the value : 1109246666
Consumer thread: 140108921554496 deletes the value : 34472492
Consumer thread: 140108921554496 deletes the value : 1658551151
Consumer thread: 140108921554496 deletes the value : 1646031817
Consumer thread: 140108921554496 deletes the value : 2114864384
Consumer thread: 140108921554496 deletes the value : 2019817090
Consumer thread: 140108921554496 deletes the value : 90771015
Consumer thread: 140108921554496 deletes the value : 1977802548
Consumer thread: 140108921554496 deletes the value : 1337378708
Producer thread: 140109036906048 adds the value : 662295424
Consumer thread: 140108913161792 deletes the value : 662295424
Producer thread: 140108946732608 adds the value : 1952746478
Producer thread: 140108946732608 adds the value : 1782607749
```

Thanks.

Comment: "My expectation was that [...] would operate randomly." What is it based on? "the problem" I don't see any.

Comment: Try putting `volatile` on any var that is in your `while` loops (e.g.) `cnt` et. al.

Comment: You might be interested in [`pthread_setschedparam()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html) with a fifo or rr policy and [`sched_yield()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) if you want to control what order threads run in. Without the real time scheduling stuff, the default behavior is left up to the OS, and releasing/acquiring a mutex/condition variable wait is *not* necessarily a  point where the running thread will reliably change.

Comment: @n.m. 
I assumed that each producer thread would individually add values ​​to the buffer. But it seems that the same thread continues to fill the buffer.

Comment: @CraigEstey Tried it, but the cnt changed properly.

Comment: @Shawn I don't know if I can use it because there is a problem solving condition, but I personally will try to use it for problem solving. thank you very much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> My expectation was that different producers or consumers would operate randomly.

That's not what threads are for.

In your case, what's happening is, neither of your two threads does any work outside of its critical section. If one thread is doing any work, then the other must either be waiting to acquire the mutex, or waiting on the condition variable. You aren't allowing them to do any real work concurrently with each other.

Try moving the `printf` calls outside of the critical sections (I.e., move it after the `pthread_mutex_unlock` call.) Calling `printf` is the most CPU-intensive thing that either of your threads does. Formatting a string is more work than just plucking a value from a queue. After one thread unlocks the mutex, the time it spends working inside of `printf` (or occasionally, waiting for I/O inside of `printf`) will give the other thread a chance to wake up and acquire the mutex.

Comment: The `pthread_cond_signal()` calls can also be moved outside the critical regions.  That might help slightly with the OP's issue, but the main reason to do it is to adhere to the principle of keeping one's critical regions as small as possible.